# Grouping an ObervableCollection and combining or joining Values checking for a null or empty value and putting them in order

Tags: c#

I have an Observable collection of objects that needs to be grouped together and the quantity property summed, but also the the other some properties of the object need to be grouped into a new string separated by a comma or some form of separator if they are unique and for my sku property it should be assigned the first or distinct with a value. So for example my observablecollection has data like this..

[image]

so the resulting collection should be something like this...
[image]

I came up with this linq statement

```
var groupedList = scannedList.ScannedCollection
                .GroupBy(l => l.UPC)
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    UPC = g.First().UPC,
                    Sku = string.Join("|", g.GroupBy(sku => sku.Sku).Select(s => s.First().Sku)),
                    Location = string.Join(", ", g.GroupBy(loc => loc.Location).Select(k => k.First().Location)),
                    ReferenceCode = string.Join(", ", g.GroupBy(rc => rc.ReferenceCode).Select(r => r.First().ReferenceCode)),
                    Quantity = g.Sum(q => q.Quantity),
                });
```

but what ends up happening if there are empty values in the properties that are getting grouped with a seperator they have A,,B or skunumber2||skunumber

[image]

How can I remove the empty or null spaces and put the combined values in descending or ascending order?

Comment: Just do a `Where` before the `GroupBy`: `Sku = string.Join("|", g.Where(sku => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sku.Sku)).GroupBy(sku => sku.Sku).Select(s => s.Key));`

Comment: Much appreciated, @Knoop, finished it off with your help with     `Sku = string.Join("|", g.Where(sku => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sku.Sku)).OrderByDescending(sku => sku.Sku).GroupBy(sku => sku.Sku).Select(s => s.First().Sku))`

Comment: Since `Sku` is the `Key` for each group, it's more efficient to `.Select(s => s.Key)`